# printf format string lint warning

Tags: c, printf

I'm stuck fixing ancient code, and here is today's issue:

```
output_file_status = fprintf ( data_file, "%03d%08s%+014.2f%06.3f%",
    LongValue, CharStarValue, Double1, Double2 );
```

Lint32 produces: Lint32 results in “malformed format string”

1) Do you all agree the format string can not end in a `%` sign? I don't believe a standalone `%` has meaning.

2) When I either remove the trailing `%`, or append an additional `%`, I still get the same warning.

This is using the Oracle Pro*C compiler (so the CharStarValue is actually a (char*)VarChar.arr ).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct that `%` by itself at the end is an error. It should be `%%` to produce one literal `%` in the formatted output.

It might be that your linter is also complaining about the use of `%03d` with a `long` value. That should be `%03ld`.

Comment: Thank you Greg, good catch.  I didn't think 32-bit compilation cared about that (vs 64-bit).  I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: @frododot: 32-bit vs. 64-bit is irrelevant. The format string has to match the *type* of the argument, not just its size. (If the types don't match but the sizes do, you *might* get away with it, but it's still incorrect.)

Comment: Agreed that it is the type that matters, but a on a 32-bit, sizeof long == sizeof int, so lint didn't complain.  Changing "%03d" to "%03ld" did not affect lint's warning.  I did remove the terminating '%', as that was a definite nuisance :-)

Answer (score 2):

Taking it piece by piece:

"%03d" expects an `int`.  OP supplies a `LongValue`.  With a `long`, specifier should be **"%03ld"**.

"%08s" expects a pointer to `char`.  OP supplies `CharStarValue`.  OK.  But the "0" in the specifier is **undefined behavior** for a `%s`.  Recommend **"%8s"**

"%+014.2f" expects a `double`.  OK.  Flags '+', '0' are OK.

"%06.3f" expects a `double`.  OK.  Flags '+', '0' are OK.

"%" should have something after it else **behavior is undefined**.  Recommend removal or "%%".

---

To OP's 2 points

1 A proper format should not end with a lone `%`, but may end with paired `%%`s.
A standalone `%` introduces "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined" C11 7.21.6.1 9.

2 To get rid of all warnings, try `"%03ld%8s%+014.2f%06.3f"`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.  I was also uncertain of the %08s, and appreciate your included references.

Comment: @frododot C11 7.21.6.1 6 "The flag characters and their meanings are: - ... + ...  space ... # ... 0 For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width rather than performing space padding, except when converting an infinity or NaN. If the 0 and - flags both appear, the 0 flag is ignored. For d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions, if a precision is specified, the 0 flag is ignored. **For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.**